# What's wrong with my use of jQuery's getScript?

Tags: jquery, getscript

I want to dynamically load a javaScript file, and I think getScript is supposed to do that. But if so, what am I doing wrong?

I have testfile.js with a function test(). I try to load it with getScript instead of using `<script src="testfile.js"></script>`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function test() {
 console.log("passed");
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $.getScript("testfile.js").done(function( script, textStatus ) {
     console.log("loaded");
   })
   .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
     console.log("failed");
 });
 test();
</script>
```

Comment: `$.getScript` is an asynchronous operation. You'll have to call `test()` inside the done callback.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I thought the done/fail callbacks were never reached, but they are.

Answer (score 1):

JJJ correctly points out I was treating it as synchronous, but it's asynchronous, and I need to use the done callback. (JJJ was kind enough to not point out there'd be no point in the done callback if it was synchronous.)